# Angle between given planes

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

> If the angle between the planes given by $6x^2+4y^2-10z^2+3yz+4zx-11xy=0$ is $\cos^{-1}(k)$, then the value of $k$ is equal to?

Which concept am I supposed to use here? How can I separate the planes?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Wolfram Alpha factored the left hand side as $$(2 x - y - 2 z) (3 x - 4 y + 5 z).$$

Can you take it from here?